# How to spool or echo comments Oracle

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I'm new to oracle and trying to spool comments/line into file using a bash script.but only query output is getting spooled not the comment(Total No Of Students in Class).

Below is the script which i am using:

```
sqlplus -s test/test<<EOF
set echo on
spool abc.txt

--------------------------------------
--Total No Of Students in Class.
--------------------------------------
select id ||','|| name from students ;
EOF
```

Expected output:

```
--------------------------------------
--Total No Of Students in Class.
--------------------------------------
1,joe
2,Tom
3,Jim
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle `--` is comment syntax, so SQL*Plus ignores this:

```
--------------------------------------
--Total No Of Students in Class.
--------------------------------------
```

To display it you need to use the SQL*Plus `prompt command:

```
prompt --------------------------------------
prompt --Total No Of Students in Class.
prompt --------------------------------------
```

Also you should end your SQL*Plus script with `spool off`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot spool comments into file. but Inside PL/SQL procedure, you can use

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('My comment Line');
```

or in SqlPlus

```
prompt My Comment Line
```

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` is a PL/SQL command, so it's not going to be any use in a pure SQL context.